# Parse with Nokogiri and then save to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I need a big list of cigar brands to save in database. Can it be done with nokogiri? Do you know any good tutorials how I can save the list to the database?

Comment: This is too vague. We have no way of answering either question with anything but a "maybe" unless you provide a lot more data.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty vague question, but I'm assuming you're looking at Nokogiri because your list of cigar brands is in XML. I'll also assume that you're using ActiveRecord to connect to your database and that you have a Brand model. Here's the sample XML:

```
<brands>
    <brand><name>Brand One</name></brand>
    <brand><name>Brand Two</name></brand>
    <brand><name>Brand Three</name></brand>
</brands>
```

I'm assuming that your Brand model has an attribute called "name." To parse the above and save it you'd do something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML( File.read("/path/to/file.xml") )
doc.xpath("/brands/brand/name").each do |record|
    Brand.create(:name => record.text)
end
```

If you have any questions about the xpath syntax, w3schools has as good a syntax reminder as anyone (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).